# Geoserver time dimension features not showing

Tags: geoserver, wms, wms-time

I have a WMS layer from PostGIS data store. Setup is below on a figure. I have two attributes start and end of interval.

[image]

Temporal extent of layer is obviously calculated from start attribute. See two figures below:

[image]

[image]

Geometry viewer from PostGIS shows all the features. See figure below.

[image]

If I go to preview layer in Geoserver without time filter I have some features missing (with most recent end timestamp 2018-12-18T00:00:00).

[image]

If I include time filter which corresponds to temporal extent of the layer (i.e. &time=2018-10-05T00:00:00.000Z/2018-12-18T00:00:00.000Z/PT12H), than I get all the features:

[image]

My question is: Why are all the features not shown when I set that latest features should show. Why GS is ignoring features with latest timestamp? How can I get all the features without time filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `START` is also defaulting to the largest value in the domain, in the same way as the `END` is. So you only get features that occured on the last day of your data set.

Answer (score 2):

Ian's answer is correct, but to rephrase the same concept, it's because when you enable time, time filtering is always present, even if you don't specify it in the request, and if you don't specify it, it's using the default time value.